# how to download large amount of files using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, request

I have a total `25000` image links. I am trying to download these images to my local using nodejs `request` package.
up to `14000` to `15000` it is downloading after that I am getting below errors.

**error**

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1148:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 'factory.jcrew.com',
  port: 443,
  localAddress: undefined }
internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\sangram\fiverr\New folder\public\JCREWFCT\99105154564.png'
```

**Code for download**

```
var request = require('request');

var download = async function (uri, filename, callback) {
  await request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    if(err) {
      console.log(filename);
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};

await download(d.image_link_1, saveDir, function () {
});
```

can anyone guide me what I need to do to download these may files at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that there is an `EMFILE` error which should be handled appropriately by queuing up `open` and `readdir` calls. Use [`graceful-fs`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) for that.

The other problem that you might run into with such large number of async requests has to do with pooling and allowed `maxSockets`. If that happens, set the pooling to `false` or set the `maxSockets` parameter appropriately. Or, instead of setting maxSockets on request, you can set the `http.globalAgent.maxSockets`, like:

```
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 30000;
```

Check out: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: can you ell me what is the use of `graceful-fs` package ?

Comment: I will quote the graceful-fs github page:
Queues up open and readdir calls, and retries them once something closes if there is an EMFILE error from too many file descriptors.

Comment: and how to set the pull false?
`pool: { maxSockets: 250 }`

Comment: Yeah.. In your case go for `pool: {maxSockets: Infinity}`

Comment: you used garceful-fs and changed the pooling on requests?

Comment: Check the edited answer for info on setting up maxSockets at https level.